# How to delete entities in many-to-many relationship in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, many-to-many

I have two entity-classes: Account and Role. These are mapped with the many-to-many relationship. I want to delete one account from database. The code below is working for me, however, I believe there is a better approach.

My `Account.class`:

```
public class Account {

    //some code

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(name = "account_role",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "account_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")})
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

}
```

My `Role.class`:

```
public class Role {

    //some code

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
             cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE , CascadeType.PERSIST/*, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH*/})
    private Set<Account> accounts = new HashSet<>();
}
```

This is my mapping in PostgreSQL

[image: Db map pic]

## TL;DR

Code below works fine, what is the better approach?

```
@Override
public void deleteUserAndHisTokensById(Long accountId) {
    Account accountToBeDelete = accountRepository.findDistinctById(accountId);
    accountToBeDelete.getRoles()
            .forEach(role -> {
                Set<Account> updatedAccounts = role.getAccounts()
                        .stream()
                        .filter(account -> !account.equals(accountToBeDelete))
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
                role.setAccounts(updatedAccounts);
                roleRepository.save(role);
            });
     
        accountToBeDelete.setRoles(null);
        accountRepository.deleteById(accountId);
    }
```

Comment: Add `cascade = { ...., ...., CascadeType.REMOVE}` in `Role` relationship then use just `accountRepo.deleteById(accountId);` and will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you add `CascadeType.REMOVE`, just like @JonathanJohx mentioned. You will be able to remove it just like this:

```
accountRepository.deleteById();
```

Moreover, if you want to remove roles from accounts add `CascadeType.REMOVE` to the other side of the relationship, so you can do this:

```
Role role = roleRepository.findById(10);
Account account = accountRepository.findById(11);
account.getRoles().remove(role);
```

Comment: thank you for the mention, so this was `upvoted`. :)

Comment: It's looks strange, but adding cascade remove to not help me with this stuff.
I'm  try it on Account -> it works and delete account and role if I delete account. With Role adding REMOVE cascade do nothing, if i just call: accountRepo.deleteDistinctById(someId);
P.s thx for improving english and etc in my post